# List index out of range ConnectFour

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

This error comes. I don't know what it is. I'm a beginner programmer.

> ConnectFourBoard.py", line 58, in show_board_dynamic
>       print(self.__board[i][j], end = ""), IndexError: list index out of range

My code:

```
class ConnectFourBoard:
    def __init__(self, cols = 7, rows = 6, requiredToWin = 4):
        global __board
        self.__space = ''
        self.__board = []
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        self.Win = requiredToWin
        self.__board = [[''] * rows for i in range(cols)]

        for i in range(cols):
            row = ['']*cols
            self.__board.append(row)

    def MakeMove(self, row, col, element):
        global __board
        self.__board[row][col] = element

    def CheckForWin(self):
        return winner

    def CheckHz():
        for x in range (6):
            for y in range (7):
                row += board[x][y]
                print("%s" %row)
                row = ""
                if "XXXX" in row:
                    print("Winner is X")
                    break;

    def CheckVt():
        for y in range(7):
            for x in range(6):
                column += board[y][x]
                print("%s" %column)
                column = ""
                if "XXXX" in column:
                    print ("Winner is X")
                    break;




    def FullBoard(self):
        return True

    def FreeSpace(self, row, col):
        return True

    def show_board_dynamic(self):
        print()
        print("-------")
        for i in range(len(self.__board)):
            for j in range(len(self.__board)):
                print("|", end = "")
                print(self.__board[i][j], end = ""),
            print("|")
            print("-------")
        print()
```

Comment: Check out http://pythontutor.com

Comment: Try removing this `for i in range(cols):
            row = ['']*cols
            self.__board.append(row)` from your `__init__()`, i.e. the last lines of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have different numbers for rows and columns but iterate you over `len(self.__board)` for both of them.

Change:

```
    for i in range(len(self.__board)):
        for j in range(len(self.__board)):
            print("|", end = "")
            print(self.__board[i][j], end = ""),
        print("|")
        print("-------")
```

to:

```
    for col in self.__board:
        for val in col:
            print("|", end = "")
            print(val, end = ""),
        print("|")
        print("-------")
```

Comment: It works thank you!!! But i ended up with way too many rows when i just needed 6, do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

You should either

1. Change the board to a square so that rows=cols.
2. Remove the default parameters for rows and cols of 6 and 7 respectively.
3. Hardcode for 6 rows and 7 cols

There are many ways to fix this error of not having the rows and cols synchronized throughout the program.

```
        for i in range(len(self.__board)):
            for j in range(len(self.__board[0])):
```

This line should be fixed to this.

Comment: Will that fix the problem of having too many rows printed when i run it?

Comment: def show_board_dynamic(self):
        print()
        print("-------")
        for col in self.__board:
            for val in col:
                print("|", end = "")
                print(val, end = ""),
            print("|")
            print("------")

Comment: i've changed that line to this so i'm not sure what to do next

Comment: Please see my answer for three possible solutions. Is it still throwing an error? The comment you posted above will not work. It will iterate through the elements. Instead you want to iterate through indexes and the print the values from the index via the board.

Comment: just replace the second for loop with this "for j in range(len(self.__board[0])):"

Comment: ah I see. You iterate through cols then rows. Just replace the first for loop with "for _**j**_ in range(len(self.__board[0])):" then.

Comment: print(self.__board[i][j], end = ""),
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Your rows and cols are not in sync. The norm is rows then cols. You switch back in forth causing confusion. Just try this     for i in range(len(l[0])):
        for j in range(len(l)-1):
            print("|", end = "")
            print(l[j][i], end = ""),